# Converting relative time from CSV file into absolute time

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, spyder

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import Rbf, InterpolatedUnivariateSpline
data = np.genfromtxt('FTIR Data.csv',  skip_header=1, delimiter=',', usecols=(1,2,3), names=['Time','Peakat2188cm1', 'water']  ) 

x=data['Time']
y1=data['Peakat2188cm1']
y2=data['water']

fig=plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax2 = ax1.twinx()

ius=InterpolatedUnivariateSpline
xs = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), 100)
s1=ius(x,y1)
s2=ius(x,y2)
ys1 = s1(xs)
ys2 = s2(xs)

ax2.plot(xs,ys1) 
ax2.plot(xs,ys2)
ax1.set_ylabel('Peak at 2188 cm-1')
ax2.set_ylabel('water')
ax1.set_xlabel('RT (mins)')
plt.title('RT Vs Conc')
```

This is my code for reading data from a csv file which is an export data from my instrument. In excel file, i have manually converted the relative time into Time in minutes and got the right plot. But i want to convert the relative time directly in matplotlib when reading the relative time column in csv file.  I have tried from different examples but couldnt get through. I am very new to python so can anyone please help  with editing in my code. My actual data is in the following format. (this code is used to plot absolute time i.e. Time, which i already converted in excel before ploting in matplotlib)[enter image description here][1]

```
Relative Time,Peak at 2188 cm-1,water
00:00:51,0.572157,0.179023
00:02:51,0.520037,0.171217
00:04:51,0.551843,0.221285
00:06:50,0.566279,0.209182
00:09:26,0.022696,0.0161351
00:10:51,-0.00344509,0.0141303
00:12:51,0.555898,0.21082
00:14:51,0.519753,0.179563
00:16:51,0.503512,0.150133
00:18:51,0.498554,0.154512
00:20:51,0.00128343,-0.0129148
00:22:51,0.349077,0.0414234
00:24:50,0.360565,0.0522027
00:26:51,0.403705,0.0667703
```

Plot

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this moment, the `Time` column is still a string. You will have to convert this to minutes in some way

## `pandas.to_timedelta`

```
import pandas as pd

column_names = ['Time','Peakat2188cm1', 'water']
df_orig = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=',')
df_orig.columns = column_names

time_in_minutes = pd.to_timedelta(df_orig['Time']).dt.total_seconds() / 60
```

## semi-manually

```
time_in_minutes = [sum(int(x) * 60**i for i, x in enumerate(reversed(t.split(':')), -1)) for t in data['Time']]
```

### explanation

This is the same as:

```
time_in_minutes = []

for t in data['Time']:
    minutes = 0
    # t = '00:00:51'
    h_m_s = t.split(':')
    # h_m_s = ['00', '00', '51']
    s_m_h = list(enumerate(reversed(h_m_s), -1))
    # s_m_h = [(-1, '51'), (0, '00'), (1, '00')]
    for i, x in s_m_h:
        # i = -1
        # x = '51'
        minutes += int(x) * 60 ** i
        # minutes = 0.85
    time_in_minutes.append(minutes)
```

Comment: Many thanks for the reply. I have edited my code by converting the sting column into minutes but still getting the error. I have attached my code. If you cna kindly correct me would be great. Thanks @MaartenFabré

Comment: Sorry i found the error. Its working now. Cheers. Thanks alot, used this method earlier couple of times but i was doing a small mistake. I was missing this entry ''df_orig.columns = column_names''

Comment: @Mustafa Yousuf. Cool that it worked out for you! Could you perhaps find the time to accept the suggested answer?

Comment: Yes, i did. Thanks alot once again.